# Save picture and get a link using Java and  Tomcat

Tags: java, http, tomcat, hyperlink, image

How can I save a picture in my Java Application and get an HTTP link?

How can I then download the picture with this link in another program?

I am using the Apache Tomcat and Spring.  Is there a common way or Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Google for these keywords:

- java tomcat upload file
- tomcat servlet binary download